# Data structure representing a two-value array with 3 operations

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

Let's have `n` values. All values are `false` and can be changed to `true`.
I want 3 operations on these values with certain time complexities:

- `val(i)` -> returns value at index `i`. Time complexity - **O(1)**.
- `change(i)` -> change value at index `i` to true. Time complexity -
  **amortized O(1)**.
- `find(i)` -> return closest index to index `i`, that contains value
  `false` (if there is `false` on `i` then return `i`). Time complexity - **O(log n)**.

I don't really care about **space complexity**.
The structure is initialized at the beginning with fixed length. It doesn't really matter how much time the initizalization takes.

How should a data structure used for these operations look like?

Comment: You forget to specify the space complexity.

Comment: What about `add` and `remove` methods, needed? Complexity? Can it be of fixed size?

Comment: @Diet - looks like quite difficult question, do you know that this structure actually can exist or is it possible that true answer is: "The structure cannot exist"?

Comment: No `add` or `remove`. The structure is initialized at the beginning with fixed length. It doesn't really matter how much time the initizalization takes.

Comment: Mhh. It's easy if you allow `O(log n)` on `change` too. Then it's just a `TreeSet` (sorted set, memorize all `true` indices) for the `find` method and an ordinary `array` for the `val` method. The `change` method will need to access both (`O(1)` on the array, `O(log n)` for insertion on a tree set).

Comment: @libik - I'm certain it can exist, I just can't find the right combination/modification of standard structures.

Comment: The `find` is really hard to realize together with `change` in `O(1)` (ammortized). In order to realize `find` you need some kind of sorting. But insertion in sorted structures (due to `change`) yields `log n` again since you need to find the correct place for insertion, which certainly is not `O(1)`.

Answer (score 2):

Set up a [segment tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree) on [0, n) and, for each elementary interval `[i 2^k, (i+1) 2^k)`, store the AND of the boolean values in that interval.

`val(i)` is constant-time because it's just an array lookup.

`change(i)` is amortized constant-time if we alter the usual rootward propagation algorithm to exit early if there is no change at a particular level. This is because at any given time, the number of writes to intervals k levels from the root is at most half of the number of writes to intervals k+1 levels from the root (prove this by induction on k).

`find(i)` can be implemented in logarithmic time as follows. First observe that it suffices to find the nearest false left neighbor and the nearest false right neighbor and take the nearer of the two. To find the nearest false right neighbor for position `i`, decompose `[i, n)` into elementary intervals. Find the leftmost of these intervals that contains a false (i.e., its AND is false). Proceed leafward from this interval, checking to see at each level if the left half has a false. If it does, descend to it; otherwise, use the right half.

On a unit-cost RAM (i.e., the theoretical version of real hardware), we can get `find(i)` down to time `O(log n / log log n)` time with `O(n / log n)` words of storage by changing the tree fanout from `2` to the word size (`Theta(log n)`) and using bitwise operations.

Answer (score -1):

Use combination of hashmap and binary search tree.

Example-
Suppose boolean[] A  = { false, false, false, false}

Create hashmap  (map with key as integer and value as Object)

Iterate over each item:
1. Create object with index and value as attribute.
2. Add object to the map.
3. Add the same object to BST using index of object for position in BST.

Now do following operation:

1. Val(i) : directly get object and return value of object. Complexity (1)
2. Change(i, true/false) : again get object from map and update its value. complexity O(1)
3. Find(i) : Check if value of object in that map is false or not. If it is false return otherwise do traversal in BST to check nearest index having value as false. Note traversal of BST based on object's key can be done in O(logn). Hence Complexity O(logn)

Comment: "do traversal in BST to check nearest index having value as false" How? You didn't update the BST in Change.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Thats why i took object. The same object is in map 's value and BST node. Sorry i created map of key  as integer and value as boolean. It should have value as object and not boolean

Comment: @DavidEisenstat thats why i took object instead of boolean. That object is in map and BST both. So updating that object at one place will change on other also. Sorry i took map with key as integer and and value as object. It  should have value as object. Hope this clears your doubt.

Comment: How does Find(i) search quickly through a large number of true values?

Comment: Thats the beauty of BST. Searching in BST is O(logn)

Comment: Searching yes, but not search while filtering on value, which is what you're trying to do.